# Up until this morning my mysqli_connect was working perfectly

Tags: php, mysqli

But now, I'm getting an error: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host '

I can get to the mysql database on the server and Godaddy ran scripts that work. They said my parameters were correct but they say it's on my end. I'm talking directly to their server not a localhost. I tried it on my smart phone with a different IP and got the same message. If it's not them and not my code, what can it be? The error is on the $conn = line.

```
        $hostname = "AAAA.server.net";
        $username = "BBBB";
        $dbname = "CCCCC";


        $password = "XXXXX";
        $usertable = "tblOne";


        //Connecting to database
        $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE 
        ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");

    mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
```

Comment: is the `mysqli` class/extension still hooked up the same as always?

Comment: Did you tried to use server ip instead?

Comment: From where are you connecting to the database, a Godaddy web site?

Comment: I just put in the IP addy rather then the server name and now it works. I guess it couldn't resolve the name but will that cause me trouble down the line?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure and confirm your database host, because the error message is talking of host problem

Unknown MySQL server host

Answer (score 0):

With GoDaddy, your domain name may not be where your MySQL server resides. It depends upon your server type and your hosting plan. GoDaddy has a help page that will point you in the right direction:

```
https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/39/viewing-your-database-details-with-shared-hosting-accounts
```